# Multiple conditions for if not working

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

So, in my 'if' statement, I need to compare 12 integers (from an array). Integers 1 through 3 must all be equal, integers 4 through 6 must all be equal and so on. I somehow can't get such an if to work at all. Neither using == twice is accepted, nor is $$.

```
if (arr[0] == arr[1]==arr[2]) $$ (arr[3] == arr[4] == arr[5]) $$ (arr[6] == arr[7] == arr[8]) $$ (arr[9] == arr[10] == arr[11])
        {
            panel[1].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

This, though, doesn't work. Both == ("Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int) and $$ ("Unexpected character '$') are underlined and won't let me compile.
I thought I would do just single '==' (8 conditions then, instead of 4) like this:

```
if (arr[0] == arr[1]) $$ (arr[1] == arr[2]) $$ (arr[3] == arr[4]) $$ (arr[4] == arr[5]) $$ (arr[6] == arr[7]) $$ (arr[7] == arr[8]) $$ (arr[9] == arr[10]) $$ (arr[10] == arr[11]) 
        {
            panel[1].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

But it still doesn't work. The '=='s are no longer underlined, but it still doesnt 'expect' the dollars.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you lost open/close bracket for if statement?!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change $$ into &&.

The [conditional-AND operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.90).aspx) (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

Comment: oh lord, I can't even read.
Works now (in the second case), cool.
Thank you and sorry for such a stupid question.

Comment: Still, though, is there a way to check if many variables are equal all at once?

Comment: I would say no. You could use a for...loop to iterate over the items in the array, comparing it to the first one of the batch.